# Uploading a file without input field in HTML and using only JS Drag and Drop API

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, automated-tests

How can I pass the file upload path using the DnD javascript Api for python + selenium automation?
Previously, for uploads, I used `find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@title, "dropzon")]').send_keys('file_path')`, I was bound to input. But the layout has changed and input is no more.
I tried to execute a js script with passing the path to the file, but the call ends with an error

[image: Drop files]
[full size](https://ibb.co/Cs46n2Q)

Maybe someone has already done a similar operation ?

Examples:

```
js_upload_file_script = "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                        "const input = document.createElement('input'); " \
                        "input.type = 'file'; " \
                        "input.className = 'my-audio-input'; " \
                        "const dt = new DataTransfer(); " \
                        "dt.items.add(file);"

self.execute_javascript_with_arguments(js_upload_file_script, 'abs_path_to_file', driver)

error -> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DataTransferItemList': parameter 1 is not of type 'File'.
```

and

```
js_upload_file_script = "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                        "const input = document.createElement('input'); " \
                        "input.type = 'file'; " \
                        "input.className = 'my-audio-input'; " \
                        "const file = input.files[0]; " \
                        "const dt = new DataTransfer(); " \
                        "dt.items.add(file); " \
                        "element.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', {dataTransfer: dt}))"

self.execute_javascript_with_arguments(js_upload_file_script, 'abs_path_to_file', driver)

error -> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DataTransferItemList': parameter 1 is not of type 'File'.
```

and

```
js_upload_file_script = "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                        "const input = document.createElement('input'); " \
                        "input.type = 'file'; " \
                        "input.className = 'my-audio-input';" \
                        "const dt = new DataTransfer(); " \
                        "dt.items.add(file); "

self.execute_javascript(js_upload_file_script, driver)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.my-audio-input').send_keys('abs_path_to_file')
```

nothing is happening

and last

```
js_upload_file_script = "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                        f"var file = new File(['{resource}'], '{location_file}', " \
                        "{ type: 'file' }); " + "const dt =  new DataTransfer(); dt.items.add(file);" \ 
                        "element.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', {dataTransfer: dt}))"
self.execute_javascript(js_upload_file_script, driver)
```

a semi-working option, since I see an attempt to upload a file, and but with an error

[image: upload is error]
[full size](https://ibb.co/Qn6k7sj)

Comment: Does your web page contain file matching `//input[@type='file']` ?

Comment: @Prophet no, it doesn't, I attached the entire layout for drag&drop. Please, look above

Comment: This is not a visible element. I asked if you can locate such element with DevTools there?

Comment: @Prophet input is not in the DOM, because it is used HTML Drag and Drop API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- First I created an input in the DOM with attributes and a class for the future file

  ```
  create_input = "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                 "const input = document.createElement('input'); " \
                 "input.type = 'file'; " \
                 "input.className = 'my-audio-input'; " \
                 "document.body.append(input);"
  ```
- called the execution of the JS script for creating input on the page

  ```
  self.execute_javascript(create_input, driver)
  ```
- Then I prepared a JS script to upload the file

  ```
  upload_file = "const input = document.querySelector('.my-audio-input'); " \
                "const file = input.files[0]; " \
                "const dt = new DataTransfer(); " \
                "dt.items.add(file); " \
                "const element = document.querySelector('.c-audio-dropzone'); " \
                "element.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', {dataTransfer: dt}))"
  ```
- Then I found the element where I threw the path to the file through send_keys

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.audio_input).send_keys('absolute_file_path_for_upload')
  ```
- And called the JS script to download the file

  ```
  self.execute_javascript(upload_file, driver)
  ```